# While inserting rows using bulk insert concept how to get failure rows with data

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to insert rows using bulk insert concept followed code as it is below link https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:1422998100346727312 I want to find out insertion failed rows data

Comment: It is already answered by Thomas Kyte in the link posted by you.

Comment: there am able to get only error index and error code. In addition to that i want to get failed record with data also like errorcode:errorindex:record data- id:001 name:tom tech:oracle